# JQuery UI autocomplete not working after disabled textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Can any one suggest autocomplete is not working after textbox disable and then enable

I have one textbox which i type any character and then it populate table below of text box

like this

[image]

and after i select any value from that it will populate in textbox and after textbox will disabled and focus goes on second textbox  on second textbox i have implemented jquery `keyup` event when i click `upkey` on second textbox it will redirect to first textbox with enabled which is autocomplete textbox and when i enter one character on textbox autocomplete function is not work, and when i enter second character it is working and populate table.

what the issue on autocomplete?

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to provide your basic codes which you are using for enabling and disable the autocomplete. You can check below how to enable and disable.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
    
    $("#disable").click ( function() {
 
       $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        disabled: true
      });
 
});
    $("#enable").click ( function() {
 
       $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        disabled: false
      });
 
});
    
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div> <br>
 <button id="disable">disable</button>
 <button id="enable" >enable</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```